# No module named oauth2 - importing from google.oauth2

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, service-accounts

I am trying to utilize service accounts on a Google Cloud Platform project; however, I am getting an import error after installing the packages as directed on [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) website:

The code that breaks the app is:
    from google.oauth2 import service_account

When that line is commented out or removed the app doesn't crash; however much of what I need to do involves using service accounts to perform actions that require domain-wide access. I can't find any alternate method of maintaining authorization and performing actions for users in the domain (aside from service accounts), and I also can't find any solutions for this issue on Stack Overflow or elsewhere - any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess that you [did install the module](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation), right? Also, if you are on App Engine, don't forget to [vendor the library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring)

Comment: What version of App Engine are you using?

Comment: @Mangu yup, and I also vendored the library.

Comment: @DustinIngram do you mean app-engine-python? For that I'm running 1.9.80

Comment: @JigarGor I meant are you using App Engine Standard First Generation (2.7), Second Generation (3.7) or Flexible?

Comment: @DustinIngram I believe I'm using standard first generation